# Linq join ,group and sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have this:
I have three lists with data orders orderlines and addresses.

I want to join these lists.

```
Contents = from o in Orders
           join a in addresses on o.DeliveryAddressId equals a.AddressId
           //join ol in ordersLines on o.OrderId equals ol.OrderId 
           let ol = ShopOrderLines.Where(x=>x.OrderId == o.OrderId)
           select new Order
           {
            OrderId = o.OrderId,
            CreatedDate = o.CreatedDate,
            Status = o.Status,
            CustomerComment = o.CustomerComment,
            AdminComment = o.AdminComment,
            PaymentType = (PaymentType) o.PaymentStatus,
            PaymentStatus = (PaymentStatus) o.PaymentType,
            Firstname = a.Firstname,
            Lastname = a.Lastname,
            Sum = ol.Any() ? ol.Sum(x=>x.Quantity * x.Price) : 0
            };
```

This works fine but i also want to add the total sum of the orderLines for each order.

Something like this. sum = (ol.Vat * ol.Quantity) + (ol.Quantity + ol.Price)

I guess i have to group the resultsthen calculate`?

Anyone?

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. You're creating a new `Order` instance for *each order line* and each address. So if one order has two addresses and two order lines, you're creating four Order objects. Are you sure you don't want group join?

Comment: As a note, It looks like you are assigning two properties wrong `PaymentType = (PaymentType) o.PaymentStatus,` and `PaymentStatus = (PaymentStatus) o.PaymentType,` It looks like a typo to me, the properties are interchanged them

Comment: and why don't you have an `Address DeliveryAddress` property in your Order class (and an `IList<OrderLine> OrderLines` or something like that) ?

Comment: 1)One order has only one order has only one address.
2)Its a cast to Enum

Comment: _"I guess i have to group the resultsthen calculate`?"_ Can you elaborate on this, what groups are you thinking of?

Comment: I change my code and added let ol = ShopOrderLines.Where(x=>x.OrderId == o.OrderId) this gave me a List om orderlines to work with

Answer (score 0):

I change my code and added let ol = ShopOrderLines.Where(x=>x.OrderId == o.OrderId) this gave me a List om orderlines to work with.